# Visualise clusters with k-means

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have the following dataset:

```
    Date    Text
0   05/26/2020  è morto all'improvviso jk, aveva...
1   05/26/2020  è morto a 51 anni jk, attore, co...
2   05/26/2020  aveva 51 anni e si trovava in Italia. il rico...
3   05/26/2020  arriva a milano nel 1990 per una serie di conc...
4   05/26/2020  jk, l'attore e comico, e...
5   05/26/2020  spettacolo.it ha appreso che jk, l'...
6   05/26/2020  e' morto all'improvviso jk. cant...
7   05/26/2020  addio a jk . una morte improvvis...
8   05/26/2020  lutto nel mondo della televisione. è morto a 5...
9   05/26/2020  è morto all'età di 51 anni ...
10  05/26/2020  è morto all'età di 51 anni ...
11  05/26/2020  all'improvviso se ne è andato  ...
12  05/26/2020  è andato al supermercato  ...
13  05/26/2020  jk è morto improvvisamente a 51 ...
14  05/26/2020  è morto, a menfi, il 51enne jk...
15  05/26/2020  muore a cinquantuno anni jk, il ...
```

I would like to use clustering (k-mean) to create labels for classifying texts.
I did as follows:

```
import re
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

stop_words = stopwords.words('italian')

def preprocessing(line):
    line = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z]", " ", line.lower())
    words = word_tokenize(line)
    words_lemmed = [WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(w) for w in words if w not in stop_words]
    return words_lemmed


vect =TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=preprocessing)
vectorized_text=vect.fit_transform(df['Text'])
kmeans =KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(vectorized_text)
```

Then

```
import string as st 
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

cl=kmeans.predict(vectorized_text)
df['Cluster']=pd.Series(cl, index=df.index)
df.groupby("Cluster").count()
```

I would like to know how to visualise the results.
I have tried as follows:

```
plt.scatter(vectorized_text, cl)
plt.scatter(kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 0], kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 1], s=300, c='red')
plt.show()
```

but I have this error:

> ValueError: x and y must be the same size

due to `plt.scatter(vectorized_text, cl)`, so something is wrong there. Looking at possible solutions on the web, I found something by using the PCA. Should I consider it?

Thank you

UPDATE: After receiving the answer below, I have tried with:

```
plt.scatter(vectorized_text[:, 0] ,cl)
plt.scatter(kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 0], kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 1], s=300, c='red')
plt.show()
```

unfortunately I am still getting an error:

> ValueError: x and y must be the same size

Comment: What are the shapes of `vectorized_text` and `cl` ?

Comment: @Hugolmn: for `vectorized_text`: `<209x1245 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
 with 4718 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>`

Comment: How can I see cl's shape?

Comment: cl.shape or len(cl) should work

Comment: Thank you. So cl's shape is (209,)

Comment: Just to make sure, is the shape of vectorized_text[:, 0] equal to (209,) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shape of the `x` argument in `plt.scatter()` has to have dimension (n,) which is not the case here. You can only select one column of `vectorized_text` for the scatterplot, not all of them. Right now you `x` dimension is 209x1245, and your `y`dimensions is (209,)

### How to transform `vectorized_text` to a 1D array ?

Spoiler : you can not!
You first need to slice out one column from it, then convert it to a dense matrix (right now it is sparse matrix), and then cast it as an array.

Let's assume you want to plot the fist columns from `vectorized_text`: what you need to give as `x` to `plt.scatterplot` is :

```py
np.asarray(vectorized_text[:, 0].todense())
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Hugolmn. I am sorry, but I am not fully getting what you suggest. I should plot x,y, but correctly the shapes are different, since x is a matrix and y is an array.

Comment: You `y` dimension is the dimension of `cl`: (209,). Your `x` dimension (`vectorized_text)` needs to match the dimension of `y` so it must be (209,) as well. You need to retain only one column of your `vectorized_text` for the scatterplot

Comment: Put in other words, you cannot use a sparse matrix (`vectorized_text`) as the `x` argument unless you slice it to keep only one column.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. How could I select then the first element (I suppose) of my vectorised_text?

Comment: vectorized_text[:, 0] should allow you to keep the first column of each line

Comment: You don't necessarily want to plot the first element though, each column will correspond to one word

Comment: please see updated question. I have tried as you suggested, but I got a error about different size between x and y

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217213/discussion-between-luca-di-mauro-and-hugolmn).